# How can I get the lightning in my scene closer to that in my reference?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, photorealism

I used a sun light to get the position of the shadows and the sharpness/smoothness of the shadows right. Then I used the sky texture with the sun intensity set to 0 and the strength set to 0.1 to get everything a bit more light but I am not really happy with the outcome. I was wondering if I can even achieve this light inside Blender or if this would be better achieved in post producation or the compositor (Which I am ashamed to admit, I dont use)

Reference & My Render

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Wgu.jpg

EDIT: My Render output is to big to upload, so when I first asked the question I just used the snipping tool to cut out my render and upload it and for some reason it looked way darker then my actual render. Thats why I uploaded it to imgur.

Comment: You could just try increasing the sun lamp strength and world sky intensity simply? Do that, your scene is very dimly lit, and of course, blender can achieve any amount of powerful lighting. Its just your setup.

Comment: Increasing the intensity is not possible as that would result in different shadows. I also uploaded a better picture as the one before didnt look like my actual render so you might want to look again

Comment: So then what about increasing the intensity and adjusting the shadows again? Maybe try two different lamps, one for the shadows, one for the lighting? Or you could use an HDRI and adjust the rotation/location from the mapping node in the shader editor to get the right shadows?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the "Dynamic Sky" add-on in the Lighting section:

[image]

that allows you to create and adjust a World-space background rendering material:

[image]

that is a fairly complex Shader Material node set:

[image]

that does a fairly good job during render.  Here a hazy sky for example:

[image]

My example file: [image]

Comment: Thank I will look into that. But I am not user as to how this would help me. If you compare the too piucture I feel like a big problem for example are the missing shadows on the bathtub or the stool and I dont know how I could get them wtihout overlighting the scene. I will look into the addon though!

Comment: Okay, the addon is super easy to use and I think it really helped. If you are intersted, this is the result https://imgur.com/a/X1TKmAq

Comment: @patrick823 -- ah you want cloud shadows on the furniture?  You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Other than cloud shadows, I think he means the intensified shadows underneath the bathtub in the reference image, @james_t